# Refresh standard lightning layout after trigger modifies records (After Update)

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, trigger, lightning

On Account I have a lightning flexipage it has a custom component, standard layout. Also, There is a trigger for after update that calls a future method and it updates this account and other account records. Issue is when the user update the record from custom component then go to the standard layout on page and try to updated it gets this error

> "This record was modified by '' during your edit session. Make a note of the data you entered, then reload the record and enter your updates again."

I tried to use `lightning:empApi` or Lightning Data service Record Change, I couldn't notify the ui of change been done of After update trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refresh the current view (which includes the standard/custom lightning component) after you updating the Account record data from custom component.

That is, in the callback function of the record updating function, fire an `e.force:refreshView` event.

```
action.setCallback(this, function(response){
    // your other code
        $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();

    });
```